# Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin: No external links with Jenkins 1.643

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job, where I generate an HTML-Page as a post buildstep, containing an image link ( HTML img tag). This HTML page is published by the HTMLPublisher Plugin for each job.

This has always worked great. But since I have updated Jenkins to v. 1.643, I only see a blank page when I click the published HTML page.

I've tried out a lot of things and found out the following strange behaviour:
Since the update, I cannot embed external links into the HTML-pages I publish. 
If I embed an image from an external location (img src="somelocation/xxx.jpg), the image won't be displayed.

If I examine the HTML page with Firefox, I can see that the image tag is greyed out like it was invisible, but it is not.

If I embed a normal hyperlink, pointing to an external location, I can see the link in the displayed page, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

It is like Jenkins would not permit external links in this context.

Please help me out here :)

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Thanks to Dave Bacher, he gave me the right hint.
Look at this page to see Jenkins' new security policy.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy#ConfiguringContentSecurityPolicy-Implementation

You have to relax the rules, so that embedding external images is allowed again.

For testing it, just type the following in your script console:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox; img-src *;")
```

This will allow embedding images from any external website.

If you run Jenkins on Ubuntu and you want to set this permanently, just edit the file /etc/default/jenkins. Under *# arguments to pass to java* add the following line:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"sandbox; img-src *;\""
```

Comment: Thanks for that JAVA_ARGS line - I was trying that, and Tomcat wouldn't start - didn't realize I needed to put quotes around the whole thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is likely related to recent [security fixes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2015-12-09). See the [Configuring Content Security Policy wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) for details on how to relax the Jenkins configuration.

> The CSP header sent by Jenkins can be modified by setting the system property *hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP*:
>
> If its value is the empty string, e.g. `java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -jar jenkins.war` then the header will not be sent at all.
>
> (Warning!) This is potentially very unsafe and should only be used after reviewing the overall security setup.

You can experiment with different settings using the [Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console).

Also as the wiki page notes, make sure you've upgraded to HTML Publisher 1.10 (or later).

Comment: Thanks for the information!
I will try find the right setting and comment here, if I find anything.

Comment: I have tried to change the security setting temporariliy with the Script Console and it worked.

You have to change it like this to allow embedding images from any website:

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox; img-src *;")

The site you mention also explains how to start jenkins.war via console to have this setting permanently active.

In our case, we have installed Jenkins on Ubuntu as a service and we do not start it manually from console.

At the moment I am looking for a config file or something, where I can put these changes permanently for the service

Comment: For Ubuntu, use _/etc/default/jenkins_, see also https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you, David! I edited the open post and integrated your answers.

Comment: @ReactiveMax Thank you for giving me credit, but you should not [edit your question to contain the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question). Questions should be questions and answers should be answers.

Comment: I set mine in CATALINA_OPTS in setenv.sh in Tomcat's bin directory.

Answer (score 3):

I know the original question was for Linux, but this will also help out the Windows users... If you have Jenkins installed as a service (starting from Jenkins.exe) you will need to change the arguments in jenkins.xml for that property to persist.

If you are going to use the unsafe blank option remember to put the parameter in quotes. Below is my example line from jenkins.xml:

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx1048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle "-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= " -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080</arguments>
```

Comment: Equivalent option can be found for Linux users in /etc/default/jenkins or /etc/sysconfig/jenkins. Add the argument to JAVA_ARGS variable

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Red Hat then update  `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS`