# doxygen html page looking strange after upload

Tags: html, jenkins, doxygen

I want to upload Doxygen material to a file server. The setup is primitive: apache2 pointing to /home/me/doxygen.

I am building the docs on a Jenkins slave, shoving them to the server machine with Publish Over SSH.

When I access myserver/doxygen/index.html in Firefox, they look malformed, like the left frame has dropped into one of the middle ones. Navigation technically works, but it's unintuitive and ugly. (Locally, it displays fine on any system.)

I have close to no experience with webservers and HTML, so forgive me if I'm asking something very obvious (it seems simple). As far as I know, it could be caused by any type of server configuration I overlooked, or maybe my "upload" technique, or something with the Publish Over SSH plugin ... I really don't know where to start looking. Thanks.

Comment: Kindly elaborate what brought the downvote on?

Comment: As written, this question is far too broad. Anyone trying to help would have to guess at any of a number of issues that could be causing problems. First, check that all files are actually copied over. Next, you can get more information by using the developer tools built into most browsers to start diagnosing what's going wrong. Load the developer tools and then bring up your doxygen index. Look for console errors and errors when loading CSS and JS resources.

Comment: Well, that's true. Will do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jenkins, you could use the [HTML publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) to get your html directly into the jenkins.

Then the plugin takes care of including all used files:
[image: jenkins configure screen]

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use something with authentication. That plugin does not seem to support that.

Comment: You can use the jenkins for authentication. The html is embedded inside of the jenkins job, so you do not need anything else.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that out. It would fit better in my configuration than the Publish Over plugin. Can't try it out on the spot, though, since it really seems to require Jenkins restart.

Comment: If you're planning to use the HTML Publisher to serve content from Jenkins, you should be aware of the Content Security Policy, which limits what Jenkins will publish by default. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34682268/172599

Comment: I like this approach in theory, but it seems like ONLY the index.html file gets published. The doxygen output for my project is quite extensive including images and lots of linked documents. Is there any way to publish the entire html output folder that doxygen produces?

Comment: you can add the folder (first parameter)