# Unable to display html report with inline style?

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am using jenkins as windows services. Jenkin is unable to show inline style in html report.

How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin: No external links with Jenkins 1.643](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681852/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-external-links-with-jenkins-1-643)

Comment: Your question is about inline styles, but the root cause is the Jenkins Content Security policy, which is described in the linked question and answer. Cheers!

Comment: I have solved my problem. Actually Jenkins does not support inline CSS. To use the inline CSS we have to make some changes. We have to update jenkin.xml file. we have to put