# Jenkins and HTML Publisher Plugin create reports awfull

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

BAD 
[image]

GOOD and SHOULD BE
[image]

Ricently after update my HTML Publisher Plugin up to 1.1 1version (My Jenkins core Jenkins ver. 1.652) I have got HTML report created looking so bad. After I recover to older previous version is still looks bad.

So problem is that I can't go back to nicelly created reports as before. 
**BUT** My index.html file which I try to export to Jenkins looks so perfect in the browser.

Can you please help me with any ideas?

Comment: They seem to be missing CSS style sheets. If you know how to, you could check your browser's console to see what happens, perhaps it's just a path that is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin: No external links with Jenkins 1.643](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681852/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-external-links-with-jenkins-1-643)

Comment: The issue with CSS is caused by the Content Security Policy in Jenkins.

Comment: Thank you this is helped for me