# Jenkins show blank html instead of report

Tags: html, plugins, jenkins

I use Jenkins 1.656 and HTML publisher plugin 1.11.

I have successfully added HTML report section in the job:
[Jenkins project configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHuUn.png)

Unfortunately when I click on HTML Reports, it shows only blank [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8qsh.png).

The zip button works -- it downloads the report archive.

I will appreciate any help

Comment: I tried adding **JAVA_ARGS="-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"sandbox; img-src *;\""** as it mentioned here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681852/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-external-links-with-jenkins-1-643] but I has the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with nginx server, it was

```
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
```

changed to

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

Comment: can you help us to implement above piece of code

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue but when I executed the command below in the script console it worked. Please try:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP"," ")
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you have some JS in your report? Read this page: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy and try to relax the security rules by changing JAVA_OPTS in tomcat.conf, then restart tomcat and **clear broveser cache**

I just saw your comment, try empty parameter:
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=

Comment: Good idea; I temporarily set it to **default-src *; img-src *;**, but has the same result.

Comment: On our Jenkins configuration, we are using an empty CSP parameter, it solved our issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding one more Build step in configuration with below command:

`npm install newman-reporter-html -g`

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Answer (score -2):

For me above didn't work.
I  publish report from IBM RPT (multiple .js files and index.html).
Jenki: reads index.html, first 2 .js files, but then it cracks on the others (searching them on the wrong path.

when downloaded in zip it works fine.
thx