# Publish HTML Reports Plugin is not listing all the contents properly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I have a Jenkins job which should display the HTML report after the completion of the job, I added the publish HTML reports plugin.  But, After the completion of the job if I click on the HTML Report its not showing any content properly. If I open the same index.html manually through some browser its showing the contents.  But if I open it via Jenkins its not listing any contents.  The generated HTML report has some zip on the top right corner if I download the zip and extract it its showing all the contents required to displayed on the report.

[image: Obtained Report]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin: No external links with Jenkins 1.643](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681852/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-external-links-with-jenkins-1-643)

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue and solved by changing some default Content Security Policy in jenkins:

=> Goto Manage Jenkins -> Script Console- "then write below lines" -> Run

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");
```

Answer (score 0):

Open: /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

Find the : **JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS**

Add (with the quotes):

`"-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src *;style-src 'unsafe-inline';script-src 'unsafe-inline';img-src * data: blob: filesystem:\"`

Please note that this might pose as a security issue and you should consider reading https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy

Good luck!