# Jenkins doesn't display html artifacts directly

Tags: xslt, jenkins, testng

I have a testng based testing code testing our CI code that provides us with xslt based reports.

Earlier, it was possible to directly click the index.html file (that links to a few other html files) and see the whole page with links etc. enabled, directly from the Jenkins build artifacts page, but it doesn't do that anymore.

I have to download the whole folder and open the index.html file on my PC to be able to see the whole report.

The only change I remember making is rebooting the server after a failed Jenkins update.

Is it possible to be able to just click the index.html file from the build artifacts page rather than having to download the whole folder locally?
Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin: No external links with Jenkins 1.643](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681852/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-external-links-with-jenkins-1-643)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins has a HTML report publish plugin that will automatically cache a entire html report folder and let you specify  the index page to display it on the main job page.  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know about the plugin, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

 I'll review the risks required with relaxing the Content-security-policies, give it a shot and mark this as the answer if that gets it all working.