# text in tag is truncated by html publisher

Tags: jenkins

I am using html publisher plugin in Jenkins. Here is my configuration.

[image]

Basically, I copy a html file to workspace as report and name it as "demo.123.html". However, when I check the page, the tag is truncated, and only "demo" left.

[image]

Notice the url, I am very curious about it as it points to a directory instead of a specific html file. I checked HTML_Report and it had a htmlpublisher-wrapper.html which had the right text, but that file was not requested.

How can I fix this truncating issue. Thanks

Comment: Is this a rendering issue? Jenkins has [security controls](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) that by default prevent javascript, inline CSS and more. Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34681852/172599

Comment: @DaveBacher No, I've run the script for security controls and the report shows the layout. I am curious what file it requests as the url is a directory instead of a html...

Comment: @DaveBacher The index page in job configuration is demo.123.html, but in the report, it is truncated and only demo left. However, I checked htmlpublisher-wrapper.html, the text was correct. But this wrapper page was not requested.