# JENKINS HTML Publisher Plugin unable to click on collapse dropdowns

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have updated my Jenkins from 1.6.2 to 2.6.2 and also updated the HTML Publisher Plugin, ever since I am unable to click on the collapsible drop-downs, seems like the javacript is not working. It is there but is not showing when I click the plus sign. Also, the images links are not displaying correctly. Has anyone seen this before, any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

images are below

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be reported in the Jenkins issue tracker.

Comment: Where do I report it to issue tracker?

Comment: The issue tracker is at [issues.jenkins-ci.org](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: OK, Thank You, will create this issue there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin: No external links with Jenkins 1.643](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681852/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-external-links-with-jenkins-1-643)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem you need to edit the Content-Security-Policy in Jenkins. My answer was here:

[Jenkins Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Content+Security+Policy+%28CSP%29+for+Web+Report)

Added this line to my jenkins.xml file.

```
-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle    
"-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=script-src 'unsafe-inline';"
-jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080
```